# Validating an access token in nodejs resource server with Outh server uri in spring-boot

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

1. I have OAuth2 server[Spring-boot] which validates the clients with password credentials method.
2. The access token obtained by the Frontend client[Vuejs] uses the token to access the Resource server[Spring-boot].
3. Here, while the access token is passed by Frontend client to the resource server, the resource server cross-validated it with the OAuth2 server with the following code

   `@Configuration
   @EnableResourceServer
   public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfigRemoteTokenService extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
       @Primary
       @Bean
       public RemoteTokenServices tokenServices() {
           final RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("https://localhost:9088/oauth/check_token");
           tokenService.setClientId("fooClientIdPassword");
           tokenService.setClientSecret("password");
           return tokenService;
       }
   }`
4. Now, I m trying to implement the same with nodejs as I planned to split a particular functionality which produces overhead to the resource server written in spring-boot.
5. I don't know how to implement the cross validation mechanism in nodejs like the below code.

`tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("https://localhost:9088/oauth/check_token");`

Answer (score 0):

try the express-oauth2-bearer library it works fine
first of all install it:
npm i express-oauth2-bearer --save
and use this code in your client :
The library needs the following values to authroize requests:

- **Issuer Base URL**: The base URL of the authorization server. If you're using Auth0, this is your tenant **Domain** pre-pended with `https://` (like `https://tenant.auth0.com`) found on the **Settings** tab for your Application in the [Auth0 dashboard](https://manage.auth0.com).
- **Allowed Audiences**: Audience identifier (or multiple separated by a comma) allowed for the access token. If you're using Auth0, this is the **Identifier** found on the **Settings** tab for your API in the [Auth0 dashboard](https://manage.auth0.com/#/apis).

These can be configured in a `.env` file in the root of your application:

```
# .env

ISSUER_BASE_URL=https://YOUR_DOMAIN
ALLOWED_AUDIENCES=https://api.yourapplication.com
```

... or in your application code:

```js
app.use(auth({
  issuerBaseURL: 'https://tenant.auth0.com',
  allowedAudiences: 'https://api.yourapplication.com'
}));
```

The OpenID strategy is the default strategy for token validation. With the configuration values set in the `.env` file, the following code will restrict requests to all proceeding routes to ones that have a valid access token with the `https://api.yourapplication.com` audience and the `read:products` scope:

```js
const { auth, requiredScopes } = require('express-oauth2-bearer');

app.use(auth());

app.get('/products',
  requiredScopes('read:products'),
  (req, res) => {
    console.dir(req.auth.claims);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```

If access tokens are not expected to be signed like OpenID Connect ID tokens, add the `auth` middleware with a callback to validate as follows:

```js
const { auth, requiredScopes } = require('express-oauth2-bearer');

const validateAccesToken = async (token) => {
  const token = await db.tokens.find(token);
  if (token.expired) { return; }
  return token;
};

app.use(auth(validateAcessToken)));

app.get('/products',
  requiredScopes('read:products'),
  (req, res) => {
    console.dir(req.auth.claims);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```